# How could I solve and enter the following PDE?

Tags: differential-equations

[image: The Partial Differential Equation]

With conditions:

[image: conditions]

I tried this:

`pde = DSolve[D[D[u[x, y] y] x] == 3 D[u[x, y] y] + 2 y, u, {x, y}]`

But I couldn't use the conditions and I need to find the particular solution with those conditions.

Comment: you have syntax errors. `ode = D[D[u[x, y], y], x] == 3 D[u[x, y], y] + 2 y;
bc = {Derivative[0, 1][u][0, y] == y^2, 
   Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] == x + 3*Exp[-x]};
NDSolve[{ode, bc}, u, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 5}]` NDSolve complains now because derivatives should be lower than the differential order of the PDE.   Make sure your BC are correct. For example, on the lower edge, you are taking derivative w.r.t y. double check that is what you want.

Comment: What NDSolve is basically saying, your PDE is first order in y and in x. But your BC is also derivative of first order. the BC should be lower order derivative that the order of the PDE. So make sure your bc's are correct. For example, `DSovle` solves it, without the BC. So the problem is with the BC.

Comment: Ok, but what should I do to solve it?

Comment: I do not really need the NDSolve, it was an error, sorry. I need the particular solution with those conditions.

Comment: I tried `DSolve` with the conditions you have now, and it could not solve it. But Maple can solve it. If you want, I can show you the Maple command and its solution. `NDSolve` can't solve it. It gives error `Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x=0`

Comment: Thanks, of course I want to see it (but I don't know Maple).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> of course I want to see it

Mathematica 12.2

```
ClearAll[u, x, y];
ode = D[D[u[x, y], y], x] == 3 D[u[x, y], y] + 2 y;
bc = {Derivative[0, 1][u][0, y] == y^2 - 2*y, u[x, 0] == x + 3*Exp[-x]};
DSolve[{ode, bc}, u[x, y], {x, y}]
```

gives

[image]

While NDSolve complains about derivative at `x=0`

```
ClearAll[u, x, y];
ode = D[D[u[x, y], y], x] == 3 D[u[x, y], y] + 2 y;
bc = {Derivative[0, 1][u][0, y] == y^2 - 2*y, u[x, 0] == x + 3*Exp[-x]};
NDSolve[{ode, bc}, u, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 5}]

NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x == 0.`.
```

Maple 2020.2

```
restart;
pde:= diff(diff(U(x,y),y),x) = 3*diff(U(x,y),y)+2*y;
bc := D[2](U)(0,y)=y^2-2*y,U(x,0)=x+3*exp(-x);
pdsolve([pde,bc],U(x,y))
```

gives

[image]

Notation wise: `Derivative[0, 1][u][0, y] == y^2 - 2*y` in Mathematica, means derivative w.r.t to second independent variable, which is `y`. This translates to `D[2](U)(0,y)=y^2-2*y` in Maple. Do not confuse `D[2]` with the second derivative. This means the "second slot", which is `y` also.

So the solution it gives is

```
u(x,y) = exp(3*x)*y^2*(y - 2)/3 - y^2/3 + x + 3*exp(-x)
```